# Zoom NL5: checking second nut flush on turn?

Tags: nlhe, betting-strategy, rush-poker

Cut off in this hand has supernova VIP.  (Don't know why he is playing these limits).  No previous history with this player.  Blinds are 0.02/0.05.  6 max zoom table.

Folds to the Cut off who makes it 0.11, folds to me in the big blind with QsJs and I call.  Flop comes Ks6s4h.  I check my FD and he checks behind.  Turn is the 9s. I check again after making the flush and he checks behind.  River is the 3 of clubs.  I bet 0.15 into pot of of 0.24, he raises to 0.46 and I re-raise to 1.61.  He writes "Thanks, idiot fish" in the chat box and folds.

Any advice on how I might play this better?  I'm not sure about my action on any street here.

I felt like most FD's would have bet the flop, and a hand with As would likely bet the turn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you played fine.  Villain had nothing and you got him to pay off 0.46 on the river.

Certainly a hand to call with from the blinds.

No reason to bet the flop out of position on a draw.

I would have checked the turn hoping to get the villain to bet.  You don't want to announce you made the flush.

On the river you put out a proper sized value bet.  And a proper sized re-raise for value.  Especially given he had checked the prior two rounds I think you should bet out.

Villain was trying to bluff you off the pot, it did not work, and he got mad.

I don't get what the villain was trying to represent with that raise. It certainly looks like a value bet from you. If the intent was to bluff you off the pot I think villain should have put in a bigger raise.  Better yet just fold.

Even if villain was on a suited ace he might have checked the flop. Betting the turn if he had not bet the flop would have been wrong.  On the nuts in position would hope you hit something on the river to get action.

Answer (score 1):

I would lead the turn here because I would do so with plenty of other hands as well after the flop went check/check. You should also be mixing in some donk leads on the flop as well. Basically if you are going to flat OOP against what is probably a decent player (given the description) you need to be more active in taking away pots and especially in getting value when you have the nuts!